# SVG bulge on iOS/safari with filter, feGaussianBlur and feColorMatrix

Tags: ios, svg, safari, blur, svg-filters

I'm trying to get a gooey effect with svg. Things are fine in chrome, but look weird on Safari & iOS. Here is the example: https://codepen.io/rubenhak/project/editor/ZoBENL

How it looks on Chrome:
[image]

How it looks on Safari/iOS:
[image]

The problem is when the one circle is too far, too small or missing, the other circle gets bulged. None of this is an issue on chrome.

Code:

```html
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 500 200" width="500" height="200">
      <defs>
        <filter id="goo" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 21 -7" result="cm" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g >
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="30" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle fill="blue" r="30"  cx="80" cy="50" />
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="80" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle fill="blue" r="20"  cx="160" cy="50" />
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="160" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle fill="blue" r="20"  cx="220" cy="60" />
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="220" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle fill="blue" r="20"  cx="300" cy="50" />
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="300" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle fill="blue" r="10"  cx="350" cy="50" />
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="350" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="400" cy="95" />
      </g>
      <g >
        <circle fill="green" r="15" cx="450" cy="95" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I would compare the two results without the `feColorMatrix` to work out whether it is the blur or the color matrix filter that's broken.  Then maybe file a bug with Safari.  With a filter that simple, I'm not confident you'll be able to find a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari is clipping the output of the feGaussianBlur to the default filter region before handing it to the feColorMatrix. Chrome doesn't do that. You can fix it by expanding the default filter region.

```
<filter id="goo" x="-50%" width="200%" y="-50%" height="200%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
```

Comment: Michael, you're genius! Works great. Thanks!

Comment: I've just read enough Chromium & Webkit bug discussions :) Thanks for the upvote -  if this works for you, please accept the answer too :)

Comment: I meant to mark as answer, but just upvoted :) In case you want to see the final result: https://berlioz.cloud/pricing/